# not able to run LibGit2Sharp on Mono on ubuntu

Tags: c#, mono, libgit2, libgit2sharp

have a very simple one line console app (using monodevelop)

but getting below error.

`System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods' threw an exception. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: git2-e0902fb`

my app has reference two nuget package

- LibGit2Sharp 0.21.0.176
- LibGit2Sharp.NativeBinaries 1.0.119

`LibGit2Sharp.Repository.Init("foler path");`

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`libGit2Sharp` 0.21.0.176 nuget does have dependency on a specific native library and it requires 'version/sha' e0902fb and that is not included in the `1.0.119` or `1.0.106` native nugets. (I always build these packages from source.)

The pre-release nuget for `LibGit2Sharp` 0.22.0-pre20151023210959 does include a native nuget dependency and pulls 1.0.6 version of the `LibGit2Sharp.NativeBinaries` which work together.

#### So:

Either use the pre-release version of `LibGit2Sharp` and it will pull in the 1.0.6 version of `LibGit2Sharp.NativeBinaries` which provides the correct 64-bit shared library (`libgit2-6aa06b6.so`) that work together:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>## Heading ##
  <package id="LibGit2Sharp" version="0.22.0-pre20151023210959" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="LibGit2Sharp.NativeBinaries" version="1.0.106" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

#### Or:

Use the release version of LibGit2Sharp (0.21.0.176) and find if a Native Nuget is available(?) with a 64-bit linux-based `libgit2-e0902fb.so`.

#### Or:

Use the release version of LibGit2Sharp (0.21.0.176) and build the native lib from source.

Answer (score 0):

Once you matched up native binaries package then on osx/linux you might run into error

> System.DllNotFoundException: NativeBinaries/osx/libgit2-821131f.dylib

In that case rename target directory in /bin from NativeBinaries to libNativeBinaries.

For detailed discussion on this see [libgit2sharp/issues/1170](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/1170)