# libgit2sharp: replace the "git pull” command

Tags: libgit2sharp

I want to use labgit2sharp to replace the command -- "git pull“ to pull my code from my gitlab. but it is not successful by using the following code:

```
using (var repo = new Repository(remotePath))
{
    LibGit2Sharp.PullOptions options = new LibGit2Sharp.PullOptions();
    options.FetchOptions = new FetchOptions();
    options.FetchOptions.CredentialsProvider = new CredentialsHandler(
        (url, usernameFromUrl, types) =>
            new UsernamePasswordCredentials()
            {
                Username = "username",
                Password = "password"
            });
    repo.Network.Pull(new LibGit2Sharp.Signature("username", emailaddress, new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now)), options)
}
```

Could you help me?
I want to know all the steps from the beginning. 
Thanks very much!

Comment: What are you using for `remotePath`? This has to be a local file path, not your remote Git source. Also post the error/stack trace that you are getting.

Comment: ok,thanks!but there has a error:Type initializer exception

Comment: how can i  solve it?  or i lack some steps?

Comment: Post your exception stack trace in your question

Comment: -  $exception {"“LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods”的类型初始值设定项引发异常。"} System.TypeInitializationException    -  InnerException {"无法加载 DLL“git2-785d8c4”: 找不到指定的模块。 (异常来自 HRESULT:0x8007007E)。"} System.Exception {System.DllNotFoundException}

Comment: The native `libgit2` library `git2-785d8c4` is not being found, have you installed the native libgit2 library (via Nuget or source & building it manually)? http://stackoverflow.com/a/35029888/4984832 https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2

Comment: yes !  i am.  i have installed nuget

Comment: Do you have the `git2-785d8c4` (`.dll`/`.dylib`/`.so`) native library that the C# library is trying to load?

Comment: i have git2-785d8c4.dll,and when  i try to load it ,it show that unable to add reference about it，and make sure this file is accessible and is a valid assembly or COM.

Comment: It is a **native** library, not a CIL-based one, since it ends in `.dll`, I am assuming you have the correct one and you are on Windows OS? If so, during the build process is it not being copied to the output directory with the CIL-based assembies (your program files and libgit2sharp.dll)?

Answer (score 1):

Network.Pull is no more used. Please try using **LibGit2Sharp.Commands.Pull()**

Comment: An example of how to use this syntax would make this answer a lot better.

Answer (score 1):

[@wonko-the-sane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/285417/wonko-the-sane) Here is a simple example of `Commands.Pull` usage:

```
    var Username = "name";
    var Password = "pass";
    var creds = new UsernamePasswordCredentials()
    {
        Username = Username,
        Password = Password
    };

    _credentialsHandler = (_url, _user, _cred) => creds;
       
    var projectRepositoryPath = "D:\local_repo";
    var repositoryOptions = new RepositoryOptions { WorkingDirectoryPath = projectRepositoryPath};
    var fetchOptions = new FetchOptions { CredentialsProvider = _credentialsHandler, };
    var mergeOptions = new MergeOptions { FailOnConflict=true,IgnoreWhitespaceChange=true };
    var pullOptions = new PullOptions() { FetchOptions = fetchOptions, MergeOptions = mergeOptions };


    using (var repo = new Repository(projectRepositoryPath, repositoryOptions))
    {
        var signature = new Signature("guest", "guest", DateTimeOffset.Now);
        var result = Commands.Pull(repo, signature, pullOptions);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here my working code for a pull for a public repository (LibGit2Sharp v. 0.26.2):

```
using LibGit2Sharp;
...
public static bool Pull(string repositoryPath)
{
    try
    {
        using Repository localRepo = new Repository(repositoryPath);
        PullOptions pullOptions = new PullOptions();
        pullOptions.FetchOptions = new FetchOptions();
        Commands.Pull(localRepo, new Signature("username", "<your email>", new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now)), pullOptions);
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        StaticObjects.FireShowExceptionMessage($"Pull Error, repository= {repositoryPath}: ", ex);
        return false;
    }
}
```